# Quel temps doit-on utiliser après “même-si” ?

Tags: grammaire, conditionnel, imparfait, concordance-des-temps

Bonjour,

Pourriez vous m’expliquer pourquoi il faut utiliser l’imparfait après “même si”dans cette phrase:

“Même si nous arrivions à prendre un taxi maintenant, je doute que nous puissions arriver à l’aéroport à  l’heure à cause de tous ces embouteillage qu’ils ont annoncés à la radio.”

D’après ce que je sais,
Même si+ l’imparfait, on utilise la conditionnel présent dans la proposition principale.
Même si+ plus que parfait, proposition principale :conditionnel passé.
Mais ici, la proposition principale “je doute que...” , c’est de l’indicatif présent. C’est pourquoi je n’ai pas compris la raison d’utilisation de l’imparfait après “Même si” Ici.

Merci d’avance!

Answer (score 3):

La conjonction "si" peut requérir:

- soit le présent de l'indicatif, dans le cas d'une hypothèse simple, potentielle ou récurrente, donc non localisée dans le temps. exemple:

"*Et si le fouet se casse, il frappe avec le pied*" (Victor Hugo)

- soit l'imparfait dans le cas d'une situation irréelle ou d'une hypothèse incertaine:

"*Si vous étiez vivants, vous prendriez Narbonne*" (Victor Hugo)

D'autre part, la subordonnée peut même requérir le futur, comme ici:

"*Si vous venez, vous apporterez du pain*"

Dans ce dernier cas, l'emploi du présent indique que l'hypothèse est assumée comme très probablement vraie, et fait référence à un futur proche.

De fait, la phrase que vous citez aurait aussi bien pu être:

*"Même si nous **arrivons** à prendre un taxi maintenant, je doute que nous puissions..."*

Cette variante semble même préférable à celle que vous citez, en raison de l'affirmation "*maintenant*". Cependant, l'usage de l'imparfait en opposition à "*maintenant*" indique  ici que l'hypothèse d'obtenir un taxi, pour une raison non précisée mais qui doit exister dans le contexte, est hautement improbable, sans quoi l'auteur aurait utilisé le présent.

Comment: Il me semble que ce futur est exceptionnel dans ce contexte; tel que je   perçois le contexte, le futur ne peut être que le futur jussif (futur à valeur d'impératif).