# Même si c'est / c’était le cas - temps

Tags: imparfait

Bonjour,

A s'approche de B et l'invite à le suivre.

> B ne semble même pas surpris et même si c’**est** le cas, il ne le montre
> pas.

Je pense qu'il faut employer le présent ici en raison du présent de la deuxième partie *il ne le montre pas*. Pourtant, j'ai des doutes : à mon avis, *même si c’**était** le cas* conviendrait mieux parce que B ne parait pas surpris. Mais que faire alors du présent du *il ne le montre pas* ?

Comment: Voir cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42731/quel-temps-doit-on-utiliser-apr%C3%A8s-m%C3%AAme-si) et si elle ne suffit pas modifier votre question ou en poser une autre.

Comment: @LPH Merci, je l'ai vue, mais j'ai pensé alors que "même si" et "si" ne suivent pas nécessairement la même logique. Là, les exemples contiennent "si". Mais oui, Mogu et BBBreiz ont raison, la phrase doit rester cohérente.

Comment: @LPH _Même si c’**est** le cas, il ne le **montre** pas_ ou _Même si c’**était** le cas, il ne le **montrerait** pas_

Comment: Il y a une question de contexte; qu'est-ce qui doit être dit ? Il ne le montre pas dans ce cas précis ? (alors « montrerait » ne convient pas).

Comment: @LPH A invite B à le suivre. B se lève. A pense : Il ne semble même pas surpris et même si c’est le cas, il ne le montre pas. Est-ce plus clair ? Oui, je pense qu'il faut utiliser le présent, l'autre version est incorrecte.

Comment: @LPH Parce que c'est un fait, B, étonné ou pas, ne laisse rien paraitre.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

je dirais plutôt :

> B ne semble pas surpris et même si **c'était** le cas, il ne le
> **montrerait** pas.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Je pense que dans mon contexte, il faut "présent / présent" parce que B ne laisse rien paraitre. A ne sait pas si B est surpris ou non.

Comment: Peut-être en effet attendre d'autres avis. Mais c'est à mon sens compatible: "...et même si c'était le cas (présentement), il ne le montrerait pas (maintenant)." Sous cette forme, on n'affirme rien sur le sentiment réel de B.

Comment: Oui, mais, à mon avis, le sens de la phrase est alors un peu différent. "ne le montre pas" veut dire qu'A voit clairement que B n'est pas surpris. Il peut être surpris intérieurement, mais on n'en sait rien. Selon le visage de B, on ne peut rien deviner.

Comment: "ne le montrerait pas" signifie soit la possibilité (1) soit l'irréel du présent (2). Quoique la première option est assez proche du présent...